# How to stop command if user focuses cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have textbox that flashes automatically 8 times on load. I want the flashes to stop(), and show() the textbox if the user focuses cursor on textbox. Help kindly appreciated.

**http://jsfiddle.net/4UeLg/2/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".textbox").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/4UeLg/5/). You just need a `focus` handler.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".textbox").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);

        $('.textbox').on('focus', function () {
            $(this).finish().show();
        });
    });
```